# Kerberos SSO with Java7 not working for some minutes after client reboot

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, active-directory, kerberos

We have a Kerberos SSO enabled product that runs in a Tomcat container under Java7. It generally works, but when a client (some Windows box) has just rebooted, it takes a few minutes until SSO works again.
Why is that? Is there a way around this?

Comment: well atleast in windows, OS itself manages a cache called MSLSA. Windows automatically fetches SSO tickets for it. I guess the daemon in windows responsible for it takes a while to get the ticket.

Comment: Thats a good guess, and I suspected something similar. However, I forgot to mention that a similar app does not have this issue, and I can't for the life of me figure out what the difference is.

Comment: probably your app dosent rely on the windows fetched tickets at all and by some means getting its own ticket. Can you tell me what the app is? It might be programatically getting it. I wrote some software which does that so its worth a shot investigating.

Comment: The app is using the Java GSSAPI and Kerberos implementation, with all the standard java.login.config and krb5.ini stuff that goes along with it.

Comment: Well unless your code uses LoginContext login(), you will never be fetching tgt on your own. Then you will rely on OS to get it for you. Otherwise it will fetch the TGT. GSSAPI on its own only cares about service tickets.

Comment: Not sure I got what you meant. The app has keytabs configured for its service account, and users usually log on via IE SPNEGO, because SSO is enabled.

Comment: perfectly fine. Since it is using Java GSSAPI, it fetches service tickets seemlessly. However GSSAPI is not adequate for TGT management (which OS does in case of Windows). You could do the same thing with Java LoginContext Class login() method. For instance - Tomcat uses this method to do server side auth in case of Spnego Auth